# скачать картинки php

Tags: php

```
if(!empty($this->request->post['product_category'])) {
        $product_image = $this->model_account_download->getImage($this->request->post['product_category']);
        foreach ($product_image as $image) {
            $fileName = basename($image['image']); 
            $filePath = 'image/' . $fileName;
                header("Cache-Control: public");
                header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
                header("Content-Type: application/zip");
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$fileName");
                readfile($filePath);
        }
    }
```

Так получается выгрузить только одну картинку, если возможность выгрузить все картинки zip архивом ? или что бы выгружались все картинки ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создаем архив с файлами

```
$files = array('file1.jpg', 'file2.jpg', 'file3.jpg');
$zipname = 'images.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach ($files as $file) {
  $zip->addFile($file);
}
$zip->close();
```

И скачиваем его

```
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipname);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
readfile($zipname);
```

Comment: Подскажите, а как получить массив изображений из текстового файла? Допустим у меня есть txt файл и в нем перечислены картинки с новой строки.